# Boot multiple extracted ISOs from USB

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, live-usb

All, (again)

I am trying to make a live USB for multiple linux CDs.

I have made a folder named "linux" on the root of the USB and in it is folders for:

```
Ubuntu Desktop 13.04 "ubuntu1304"
Ubuntu Server 13.04 "ubuntuserv1304"
Ubuntu Gnome 13.04 "ugnome1304"
Back Track 5 "backtrack5"
```

The folder name is on the right in quotes.

I am trying to boot from them but I keep getting into a busy box term and I want them to boot into the live environment.

Here is my menu.lst:

```
default 0
#gfxmenu /NST/GFX-BOOT.GFX (Working GUI menu for after the main system works)

title       Windows Menu
find --set-root /bootmgr
chainloader +1
boot

title       Ubuntu Desktop 13.04
kernel /linux/ubuntu1304/casper/vmlinuz
initrd /linux/ubuntu1304/casper/initrd.lz
boot
```

Note I would like the system to be able to boot on more than one computer.

Comment: The full roll up of the system is as follows:
`(32 GB USB 2.0 Flash drive
2 WIN PE images,
1 OPHcrack ISO,
1 NT Offline Password utility ISO
1 Extracted Ubuntu Desktop 13.04 ISO
1 Extracted Ubuntu Server 13.04 ISO
1 Extracted Ubuntu Gnome 13.04 ISO,
1 Extracted Backtrack 5 ISO,
The system starts to Windows Boot Manager (BCD) there you can boot to OPHcrack Win PE or NT offline. There is a choice to open GRUB menu and boot from the Extracted ISOs, each with there own entry.)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gotten it to work properly now. Here is how to make your own custom Windows/Linux AIO system:

1. Download [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) and [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/Download/Register/1). (you do not have to register to download just push download)
2. Use YUMI to install the Windows setup onto the media.
3. Delete all of the folders from the Windows Installation disk.
4. Use EasyBCD to install BCD onto the media.
5. Configure the Windows Boot manager with EasyBCD. *E.G. Add Windows PE to the menu*
6. Use YUMI to add all of the linux distros and tools you want (it will set YUMI to boot first on the drive)
7. You can do all of the custom configurations with the files YUMI created. *E.G. Replacing text and a custom logo*
8. (Optional) In EasyBCD add an option to boot (linux) from the thumbdrive. *E.G. Go back to linux menu*
9. (Optional) Rename the flash drive and add an autorun file for extra customization.
10. Remove the flash drive and boot from it (keep it in if you are trying to boot from it on the same computer.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this would be something that might do the job for you.  I use [Yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/), and I have created a bootable USB with 6 different Linux distributions, Windows 7, and 4 others utilities, and antivirus apps.  Take a look at it, it might do exactly what you need.

Comment: I tried it but I would like to make my own system.
What I would really like is to boot directly into the live CD environment.
I start by booting into Windows Boot Manager which holds all of the windows functions then I boot into GRUB from which I would like all of my Linux functions. But I cant get it to boot properly...

Comment: Oh I also use a system called Windows PE, Which is like a live CD for Windows. It is not stored in a ISO file but in a WIM file which I can't boot from in GRUB, only Windows.

Comment: How is that going to start the Linux systems...?
P.S. I use Winbuilder

Comment: Sorry, take a look at [this](http://www.thefreecountry.com/utilities/multi-boot-managers.shtml) see if it helps.  I will go ahead an delete the above comment.

Comment: I have taken a look at your like and I understand boot loaders (obviously not enough to make my project work). My idea is to have two installed on the device: BCD and GRUB. The PBR would  be pointing to BCD and then BCD could load GRUB (like chain loading). You could switch from GRUB to BCD as you wish via menu entries. I am looking into exFAT for the FS..

Comment: I don't know if Yumi is capable of doing that.  I can research it more if you'd like.

Comment: I have gotten my system to work see the answer below for more details.